# I created a Start File; When used, though, the materials are broken

Tags: startup-file

This program, I tell you...

So, I created a Start File so that I don't have to do a bunch of the same thing when I create a scene. The start file loads just fine when I open it and look around.

But Then I select: FILE - DEFAULTS - SAVE STARTUP FILE

And the very next project, when Blender loads: Pinksville. Most of my materials - which previously loaded with no problem - are now broken.

Any ideas? I could share the blend but it wouldn't really matter as it's the material connections that's the problem.

Also: I realize I can pack everything into the Blend. I've done that for the time being, but I'm just wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing. This was working with no problem, but now suddenly it doesn't.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Even i have similar problem

Comment: pink means something was moved or missing. fix the file path.

Comment: @Timaroberts is right. Blender can use both absolute or relative paths. See what works best in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pink means that something was either moved, or is now missing.

The first thing to do is to run File>External Data>Report Missing Files* and *[File](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/info/file.html#file)>External Data>Find Missing Files* to report and locate the missing files.

Note from the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/info/file.html):

> **Report Missing Files**
>
> This option is useful to check if there are links
> to unpacked files that no longer exist. After selecting this option, a
> warning message will appear in the Info editor’s header. If no warning
> is shown, there are no missing external files.
>
> **Find Missing Files**
>
> In case you have broken links in a blend-file, this option will help you to fix the problem. A File Browser will show up. Select the
> desired directory (or a file within that directory), and a search will
> be performed in it, recursively in all contained directories. Every
> missing file found in the search will be recovered. Those recoveries
> will be done as absolute paths, so if you want to have relative paths
> you will need to select Make All Paths Relative.

Once you have fixed your file paths, save your [start-up file](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/files/startup_file.html#startup-file) again with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Comment: THANK YOU. What must have happened was, upon reinstall, Relative Paths was selected. Then, the moment it's adopted as the Start File, those relative paths are broken (because the file is moved into wherever Blender stores the default start-file.